# ROS Algorithms & sensors

Tags: ros, algorithm

I am trying to implement boustrophedon algorithm using mobile robot. Can I implement this without map? I am planning to use dimensions (x,y) of the farm as reference assuming it is rectangular in shape. Has anyone tried this method? What sensors should I use? Is there can Ros package available for this ?

Comment: Have a look at this thread. https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/implementing-a-boustrophedon-algorithm-in-a-given-room-with-obstacles

Comment: I have always heard this called "ranking".