# 3D path planning for coverage of a given surface

Tags: path-planning, uav, drone, 3d-model

I have a 3D model of a complex object. I have been able to generate all possible points that are around 1 m away from the surface of any part of the object, so the collision is not possible:
[image: group available points]
[image]

Now my task is to generate a path for a robot that cover the whole area with set distance between scanning paths. Is there any known 3D path planning for coverage algorithm that can be used here? Is there any example of implementation? Picture no. 2 is a simple algorithm connecting dots after sorting and grouping points in given level. Unfortunately it will not work in more complex situations.

Comment: This might help: [Implementing a boustrophedon algorithm in a given room with obstacles](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/7660/9176)

Answer (score -2):

maybe what you're looking for can be solved by referring to the solution mentioned in
[Implementing a boustrophedon algorithm in a given room with obstacles](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/implementing-a-boustrophedon-algorithm-in-a-given-room-with-obstacles).

Could you please help me out with how I can place the points on the given surface? Did you use an STL file to generate these points? Also, did you find out some other way to solve this CPP problem? What algorithm did you use for this project

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* anuj jain. I'm afraid that on Stack exchange *answers* need to  answer the question. If you have a related question, it should be asked as a new question (ideally referencing this one).  If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/16730)